# Multiple sorting on single index of Algolia

Tags: sorting, algolia

Can we put multiple sorting/custom ranking on single index of Algolia without creating multiple replica indexes for each sorting.

Lets understand with example suppose my application is `SalesManagement` and I create 3 replicas `MobileSale`,`LaptopSale` and `PhoneSale` and then in each one I put custom sorting to `type = 'mobile',type = 'laptop' and type = 'phone'` respectively.

Instead of doing above I just want to create one index and put sorting on compile time by sending different settings by using `IndexSetting` in my code so I don't need to create multiple indexes

Comment: No. For Algolia indices, sorting is part of the indexing process, which is why the sort order needs to be pre-defined for each index or replica. Each change to ordering/ranking requires a full re-index operation. If this was handled at query time you'd lose the real-time query speed that is the primary reason for using an index.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ranking` property of `IndexSetting` it worked for me

```
 private readonly SearchClient algoliaClient;
 private readonly SearchIndex feedIndex; 
 public AlgoliaService(  )
        { 
            algoliaClient = new SearchClient("app-id", "api-key");
            SearchIndex = algoliaClient.InitIndex(_defaultSettings.Algolia.FeedIndex);
           algoliaClient.InitIndex("user-index-name");
          
        }



 public async Task SetCustomSortingAttributes(string sortBy)
        {
            if (sortBy != null)
            {
                List<string> sortingAttributesList = new List<string>();
                StringBuilder sortAttribute = new StringBuilder();
                if (sortBy == "most_viewed")
                {
                    sortAttribute.Append("desc(most_viewed)");
                }
                else if (sortBy == "entityUniqueViews" )
                {
                    sortAttribute.Append("desc(entityUniqueViews)");

                }
                else if (sortBy == "latest")
                {
                    sortAttribute.Append("desc(latest)");

                }
                else if (sortBy == "price_asc")
                {
                    sortAttribute.Append("asc(price)");
                }
                else
                {
                    sortAttribute.Append("desc(price)");
                }
                sortingAttributesList.Add(sortAttribute.ToString());
                IndexSettings settings = new IndexSettings
                {
                    Ranking = sortingAttributesList
                };
                var setIndexSetting = await feedIndex.SetSettingsAsync(settings);
                
            }
        }
```